# Android Proximity Alerts

Tags: android

Does android Proximity Alerts works even if the phone is totally sleep?

Comment: Check out the Locale project. It will let you trigger various different task types based on location. I think it is set up in such a way that you can use it with your applications.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It will depend on the SDK version. See the discussion here: https://sites.google.com/a/bug-br.org.br/android/technical-documents/sensors-and-standby-mode

Answer (score 3):

Yes, although it will only check every 4 minutes.

Comment: Adding to that: the proximity alert feature of the locationmanager is said to use a mix of location techniques. Based on being close to a defined location alert+radius, it will use fine grained or coarse grained methods. That is done to conserver battery life.